# How do I get PHP to include an HTML file and change DIV align attribute?

Tags: php, html, css, include, preg-replace

How do I go about including an html file in my php page and change its `div`s tag, `align="center"` to `align="left"` that was loaded from the HTML file.

Line to change in `roomchanges.htm` :

```
<div id="Room Changes_1871" align="center" x:publishsource="Excel">
```

to

```
<div id="Room Changes_1871" align="left" x:publishsource="Excel">
```

I have tried the following but it does not work, I'm new to advanced php so any help world be appreciated:

```
<?php
$string = include('import/roomchanges.htm');
$string = preg_replace('center', 'left', $string); 
?>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/include it does NOT "return" whatever you're including. it executes the included file in-place, as if it has been literally cut&pasted into the file the include() directive is in. you probably want `file_get_contents()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php
   $string = file_get_contents('import/roomchanges.htm');
   $string = str_replace('center', 'left', $string); 
   print $string;
?>
```

And, if you want to save the page again:

```
<?php
   $string = file_get_contents('import/roomchanges.htm');
   $string = str_replace('center', 'left', $string); 
   file_put_contents('import/roomchanges.htm',$string);
?>
```

Comment: I have tried the code but it does not display the html on the PHP page, the rest of the page display fine but the html is not produced.

Comment: do you want to display the HTML?

Comment: The first solution will do that, place the php where you want the html to be

Comment: I did try the first code but, the contents of the html was not displyed with in the contents of the php< do I need to add code to disply the updated html content?

Comment: I updated it after you said that, I added `print $string`

Comment: OK I see the update now, I have tried the  print $string; but still not showing?

Comment: No errors, the PHP page displays fine, but the html is not included at all. checking the webpage code and there is no sign of it also?

Comment: wait a min, it should be `str_replace()`

Comment: That works fine for me, note that the div isn't visible since it doesn't have any content

Comment: It works perfectly.

The <div> was only one part of the html code, I did not want to paste all the code online.

Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasPowley No problem, glad I could help! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can change the roomchanges.htm to roomchanges.php and enter a variable in the align Expression.

```
if($a=="b")
   $align="center";
else{
   $align="left";
}

<div id="Room Changes_1871" align="<?=$align?>" x:publishsource="Excel">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
$string = file_get_contents('import/roomchanges.htm');
$string = preg_replace('center', 'left', $string);
```